# Eclipse throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for CaseStatement.resolveCase

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, indexoutofboundsexception, heap-memory

I'm trying to compile some code but getting what appears to be an Eclipse-specific error. Has anyone seen this? I'm looking around for possible patches but can't find any.

```
Internal validation error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15 at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CaseStatement.resolveCase(CaseStatement.ja
 va:82) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SwitchStatement.resolve(SwitchStatement.jav
 a:156) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatement
 s(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:350) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(Metho
 dDeclaration.java:137) at 
 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(Abstract
 MethodDeclaration.java:304) at 
 ...
```

The file that's throwing the error is bootbox.js. If I turn off JavaScript Validator I get

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like bug [376809](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376809) which was fixed some time ago.

Comment: Ok thanks! I see there's a patch. Do you know how I would go about applying it to my Eclipse Environment? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=215079